# Nasta Moha in Bhagavad Gita

Tags: bhagavad-gita

last time i  was reading the  bhagavad Gita, i found one  word very curious that  is nasta Moha .

Nasta  Moha  in Bhagavad Gita?  what  is    exact  meaning   of  nasta Moha ? why  lord krishna  used  this  word in Gita ?

Comment: Please add the verse in which you read that word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verse from Shreemad Bhagvat Gita you are referring to is [**BG. 18.73**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/18/73/)

> अर्जुन उवाच ।
>  **नष्टो मोहः** स्मृतिर्लब्धा त्वत्प्रसादान्मयाच्युत |
>   स्थितोऽस्मि गतसन्देहः करिष्ये वचनं तव ॥ BG 18.73॥
>
> **naṣṭo mohaḥ** smṛtir labdhā tvat-prasādān mayācyuta
>  sthito ’smi
>   gata-sandehaḥ kariṣye vacanaṁ tava
>
> Arjuna said: My dear Kṛṣṇa, O infallible one, **my illusion is now gone.**
>   I have regained my memory by Your mercy. I am now firm and free from
>   doubt and am prepared to act according to Your instructions.

---

And this is [**Adi Shankaracharya**](https://archive.org/details/Bhagavad-Gita.with.the.Commentary.of.Sri.Shankaracharya/page/n535) explaining the meaning .

> 73 Destroyed the delusion , and I have gained recognition through Thy
>   grace , O Achyuta. I am firm with doubts gone. I will do thy word.

---

The word Nashta (नष्ट) means - Extinct ,loss, lost,null etc. 
 And Moha means affection ,attraction ,delusion ,illusion ,error etc.  in general

---

Here Arjuna is using the word for disappearance of his worldly attachments with his Guru's , Brothers and Relatives. After the discourse of Shree Bhagvat Gita. Arjuna's  doubts and fear about  whether to fight the Kurukshetra war or not was over . He learned true nature of this world and about the supreme god from Shree Krishna . His attachments banished  completely and  he was  free from false knowledge , and then  was ready for the war.

---

So the word Nashto-Moha here means the disappearance of Avidya  , false knowledge , delusion , illusion , Moha etc. about the samsara from the mind .